Visual Studio SSIS 2022 - I can no longer see or add/modify Variables in SSIS packages
I'm working with Visual Studio SSIS 2022.  Until recently, I was able to view and add/modify user variables in the Variable window.  But this morning, I am no longer able to view them or to add new ones.  I downloaded the most recent version of SSIS (I think) and installed it but still no luck.  Does anyone know what the issue is and how to resolve it?

Open an SSIS solution then open the package in the solution. Right-click on the Control Flow view background, then toggle on the Variables. You can dock the Variables below the Connection Manager (or wherever you like).
